# SinglePageApplication - match sample videos from 2012 Fall update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I am trying to recreate the ASP.NET Single Page application as demonstrated by Steven Sanderson

> Single Page Applications - for desktop, mobile, tablet with ASP.NET MVC4

I have downloaded and installed the Build Preview -  http://www.asp.net/vnext
I have using NuGet, tried to update my SPA Scaffolding to ASP.NET SPA MVC 4 (Beta)
I am running Visual Studio 2012

When i create a new MVC4 application, there are some distinctive differences between what i have and the demo's i see.

Primarily, after create a new project, if you view what you have the sites look completely difference

**What Steve Sanderson Gets**

[image: Steve's Default]

**What I Get**

[image: My Default]

Then continuing to follow his example, he created a controller and has an option of

> Single Page Application with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework

This is not avaiable in my Create Controller Dialog

**What Steve Sanderson Gets**

[image: Steve's Add Controller Dialog]

**What I Get**

[image: My Add Controller Dialog]

Why are my options differen't?
What have I not installed?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new SPA template is a completely different template, as you have discovered. Short story ... the new template is revised to be a starting place, the old template was deemed too prescriptive.

The new template is a preview and will have more changes by the time it is released. The idea is you can use it as a starting point for a SPA and then add features and other libraries as needed.

UPDATE: If you want more info on what's in the latest template you can read my post here: http://www.johnpapa.net/insidespatemplate

Comment: So am I correct in saying I have the latest correct versions?

Comment: You have the latest word on SPA from Microsoft, yes. To be absolutely clear, Microsoft is no longer supporting the substance or approach you saw demonstrated by Steve Sanderson. Those bits can still be found. But so much has changed that they really are not a sound basis for development. You should look elsewhere for guidance on SPA.

Comment: Yes, it appears you have the ASP.NET Fall Preview Update. You can see details on this in my post: http://www.johnpapa.net/insidespatemplate